# Compilation error, unexpected type. required: variable found: value

Tags: java, compilation

```
public static List<Integer> gradingStudents(List<Integer> grades) {
    for(var i = 0; i < grades.size() - 1; i++){
        if(grades.get(i) >= 38){
            
            var currDiff = 5 - (grades.get(i) % 5);
            
            if(currDiff < 3){
                grades.get(i) += currDiff;
            }
        }
    }
    return grades;

}
```

I'm getting a Compilation error, unexpected type. required: variable found: value. Can someone nudge me in the right direction please?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Oh sorry, this one: grades.get(i) += currDiff;

Comment: A method call (`get(i)`) returns a value.  You cannot assign to a value.  (`+=` is an assignment operator.)  You probably should be using the `set` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The line
`grades.get(i) += currDiff;`
Will be processed as;
`grades.get(i) = grades.get(i) + currDiff;`

So basically the value of the sum will be assigned to the grades.get(i) which is not possible. ( As this is a value itself, not a variable)

**Solution**

What you probably need to change the code as;

```
grades.set(i, grades.get(i) + currDiff);
```

Of course I could be wrong about the solution depending on what you exactly want to do here.

Comment: Right idea but wrong syntax on the solution, you probably meant `grades.set(i, grades.get(i) + currDiff);`

Answer (score 1):

`grades` is a `List` object and `get` methods returns a value. You cannot set the value like that!

Here is what you could do:

```
public static List<Integer> gradingStudents(List<Integer> grades) {
    for(var i = 0; i < grades.size() - 1; i++){
        if(grades.get(i) >= 38){
            
            var currDiff = 5 - (grades.get(i) % 5);
            
            if(currDiff < 3){
                grades.set(i, grades.get() + currDiff);
            }
        }
    }
    return grades;

}
```